I'm not sure I fully understand Wikipedia's example of Bayesian analysis of genetic test results
So I am currently reading the Wikipedia article on Bayes' theorem1 and am confused about a statement in the section "Use in genetics: Using genetic test results".

Here's an overview of the section:

The section uses the example of using Bayesian analysis of a female patient with a family history of cystic fibrosis (CF, a rare autosomal recessive disease) but has tested negative for it, to demonstrate how this method can be used to determine the patient's risk of bearing a child with CF.
Since we know in this case that the patient is unaffected, that means that she either doesn't carry CF (is heterozygous for the W allele), or at least carries it (has one M allele). Since both of the parents could have been carriers of CF, we can draw the Punnett square as$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}&W&M\\\hline W&WW&WM\\\hline M&WM&MM\end{array}$$and so we have that there are 3 scenarios where the patient could not be affected by CF, 2 of them where she carries the mutant allele, and therefore the prior probabilities that are given are $2/3$ and $1/3$ respectively.
Then, assuming a CF test with a $90\%$ detection rate, we get that the conditional probabilities from a negative test are then 0.1 and 1. So from this, we can compute the posterior probabilities for H1: Patient carries CF and H2: Patient does not carry CF as $1/6$ and $5/6$ respectively.
While all of this makes sense to me, I'm confused about what's said in the last paragraph:

After carrying out the same analysis on the patient's male partner (with a negative test result), the chances of their child being affected is equal to the product of the parents' respective posterior probabilities for being carriers times the chances that two carriers will produce an affected offspring (¼).

My question is:

Is it supposed to be implied that the male partner could have been a carrier (but not affected by) CF, and therefore the chances of having a child with CF would be $1/144$? Given the test's $90\%$ detection rate, shouldn't we also consider the chance that the male partner actually is affected by CF (given that the test comes back negative)? (which therefore would give the actual chances of a child affected by CF to be $1/144+1/24=7/144≈4.86\%$)


I think they're working on the principle that if you actually have CF you will know from the symptoms by the time you reach adulthood.  Or actually, by the time you reach preschool.
